# Sometimes index docs very very slow

Tags: elasticsearch

Today,i find my `es cluster` index  docs very slow and precarious.

I added some log  to calculate how long to call the `bulk` `api`.

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    logger.info("begin call es bulk api");
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
      BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
      if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        throw new EventDeliveryException(bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage());
      }
    } finally {
      bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
    }
    logger.info("end es bulk api,time:"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
}
```

From the log.
`end es bulk api,time:100
end es bulk api,time:1121
end es bulk api,time:56785
end es bulk api,time:16201
end es bulk api,time:401
end es bulk api,time:87543`

I find es sometimes index docs very slow.

I use the api `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/thread_poolv&h=id,host,bulk.size,bulk.active,bulk.rejected,bulk.completed,bulk.queueSize,bulk.queue'` and find the `active.bulk` and `buld.queue` are  all less 2.

I use the command `top` and `iotop` and find the cpu usage and disk io are all very small.

How to find out where the problem is?
Thank you

EDIT:

Example doc:
`{"name":"name1","address":"address1"}`,all docs are like it.

There are no analyzed fields.

Here are part of my cluster setting:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip1:9302","ip2:9304"]
```

Total memory:15G
Total nodes:3
every node has 2 nodes,1 master heap size 1g,1 datanode heap size 5g
Bulk size:200

Comment: What kind of documents you have and how are your mapping and settings? Do you have analyzed fields? What hardware do you use? What are your cluster settings?

Comment: have you read this article about bulk request? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html Also it's useful to check elasticsearch logs both on client, master and data node.